What is the greatest possible number of empty squares that could remain after the jumps?
There is a kangaroo in the centre of each square of a 5x5 grid of squares. Lightning strikes, and each kangaroo simultaneously jumps one square up, down, left or right to an adjacent square in the grid. What is the greatest possible number of empty squares that could remain?

Attribution:  Netherlands Junior Maths Olympiad

Wildlife frendlier version: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/59911/soldiers-in-the-parade-ground?rq=1

Damn I didn’t even know about this!!

@Mathias711: Interestingly, since the referenced question mentions Dutch Junior Maths Olympiad, it seems this question is just straight from it, and the referenced question is a paraphrase.

I would say

 16


 Here is one configuration where the results of the jumps are in yellow:
 
 This is optimum because if we consider the green squares one can see that the jumps from just these squares alone cannot result in an overlap after the jumps (if there were let say no kangaroos in the non green squares) so there has to be at least 9 squares occupied.


What do the colors mean?

Yellow = destination, green = original position.

"the jumps from just these squares alone cannot result in an overlap after the jumps" <-- this statement alone isn't true right? They cannot result in overlap among the designated destination tiles. Not in general.

Argyll let me edit it to make it clearer in what I meant

Partial answer only:
The idea for this partial answer came from Rob Pratt’s answer.
If the kangaroos jump like this:

then after the jumps, the kangaroos will occupy 16 blue squares:

and the 16 blue squares are in the shape of the number “16”!

love it! great idea

This has style :)

I see that you could also get 15 squares in the shape of "15" if the bottom row middle kangaroo jumped to the right instead! I wonder how many others could be achieved in practice? :D

You can solve the problem via integer linear programming as follows.  Let $S=[5] \times [5]$ be the set of squares.  Let binary decision variable $x_{ij}$ indicate whether square $(i,j)$ is empty after the jumps.  Let $$M=\{(i,j,\bar{i},\bar{j})\in S \times S:|i-\bar{i}|+|j-\bar{j}|=1\}$$ be the set of allowed moves from one square to another.  Let binary decision variable $y_{ij\bar{i}\bar{j}}$ indicate whether the kangaroo in square $(i,j)$ moves to square $(\bar{i},\bar{j})$.  The problem is to maximize $$\sum_{(i,j)\in S} x_{ij}$$ subject to
\begin{align}
\sum_{(i,j,\bar{i},\bar{j})\in M} y_{ij\bar{i}\bar{j}} &= 1 &&\text{for $(i,j)\in S$} \tag1\label1 \\
x_{\bar{i}\bar{j}} + y_{ij\bar{i}\bar{j}} &\le 1 &&\text{for $(i,j,\bar{i},\bar{j})\in M$} \tag2\label2 
\end{align}
Constraint \eqref{1} forces each kangaroo to move to one adjacent square.  Constraint \eqref{2} prevents designating a square empty if a kangaroo moved there.
The maximum turns out to be

 16,

with the following $x_{ij}$ values in one optimal solution:

 \begin{matrix} 1 &0 &1 &1 &1 \\ 1 &0 &1 &0 &0 \\ 1 &0 &1 &1 &1 \\ 1 &0 &1 &0 &1 \\ 1 &0 &1 &0 &1 \end{matrix}

(In this particular solution, the ones happen to resemble the count!)
It turns out that the linear programming relaxation (obtained by relaxing the decision variables as $x_{ij} \ge 0$ and $y_{ij\bar{i}\bar{j}} \ge 0$) yields the same optimal objective value, and the corresponding optimal dual solution $(\pi,\mu)$ yields a certificate of optimality:
$$\pi=
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & -1/2 & 0 & -1/2 & -1 \\
-1/2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1/2 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
-1/2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1/2 \\
-1 & -1/2 & 0 & -1/2 & -1 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
\begin{matrix}
i & j & \bar{i} & \bar{j} & \mu_{i,j,\bar{i},\bar{j}} \\
\hline
1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 1 \\ 
1 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 1 \\ 
1 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1/2 \\ 
1 & 2 & 1 & 3 & 1/2 \\ 
1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1/2 \\ 
1 & 4 & 1 & 3 & 1/2 \\ 
1 & 4 & 1 & 5 & 1/2 \\ 
1 & 4 & 2 & 4 & 1/2 \\ 
1 & 5 & 1 & 4 & 1 \\ 
1 & 5 & 2 & 5 & 1 \\ 
2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1/2 \\ 
2 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 1/2 \\ 
2 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 1/2 \\ 
2 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 1/4 \\ 
2 & 5 & 1 & 5 & 1/2 \\ 
2 & 5 & 2 & 4 & 1/2 \\ 
2 & 5 & 3 & 5 & 1/2 \\ 
3 & 2 & 3 & 3 & 1/4 \\ 
3 & 3 & 2 & 3 & 1 \\ 
3 & 3 & 3 & 2 & 1 \\ 
3 & 3 & 3 & 4 & 1 \\ 
3 & 3 & 4 & 3 & 1 \\ 
3 & 4 & 3 & 3 & 1/4 \\ 
4 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 1/2 \\ 
4 & 1 & 4 & 2 & 1/2 \\ 
4 & 1 & 5 & 1 & 1/2 \\ 
4 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 1/4 \\ 
4 & 5 & 3 & 5 & 1/2 \\ 
4 & 5 & 4 & 4 & 1/2 \\ 
4 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 1/2 \\ 
5 & 1 & 4 & 1 & 1 \\ 
5 & 1 & 5 & 2 & 1 \\ 
5 & 2 & 4 & 2 & 1/2 \\ 
5 & 2 & 5 & 1 & 1/2 \\ 
5 & 2 & 5 & 3 & 1/2 \\ 
5 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 1/2 \\ 
5 & 4 & 5 & 3 & 1/2 \\ 
5 & 4 & 5 & 5 & 1/2 \\ 
5 & 5 & 4 & 5 & 1 \\ 
5 & 5 & 5 & 4 & 1
\end{matrix}
Explicitly, if you multiply each constraint in \eqref{1} by the corresponding $\pi_{ij}$, multiply each constraint in \eqref{2} by the corresponding $\mu_{i,j,\bar{i},\bar{j}}$, and add everything up, you will get

 $$\sum_{(i,j)\in S} x_{ij} \le 16$$


+1 for (In this particular solution, the ones happen to resemble the count!)

Ty for the read. Though admittedly I was not able to understand the certificate of optimality
