# Solve the pattern! (game)

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, nonogram

Okay, so this is based off of [https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/puzzles/js/pattern.html](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/puzzles/js/pattern.html)

And, my cousin made a random pattern and gave it for me to solve.

Unfortunately, the logic is beyond me. So i'll give it to for you guys to solve!

Rules

> You have grid of squares, and you have to fill all the squares black or white.
>
> Beside each row are the lengths of the runs of black squares in that row.
>
> Above each column are the lengths of the runs of black squares in that column.
>
> Also, the numbers will appear in the order the runs appear (see below)

```
 For example, if the row looks like this: ■■■■ ■■   ■ ■  ■■, then the numbers at the side
 of the row will be 4 2 1 1 2. Note that the numbers appear in the order the runs appear.
```

If you need to, alt+254 is a black square, and alt+255 is a white square.

So here is the puzzle that was sent. My cousin says there are 3 solutions!

```
        1  1
        11111221 11
      111111122221111
      121111111121221
      _______________
   12|
  123|
    7|
   34|
   15|
 1118|
 1112|
  223|
```

And here's an image:
[image: my puzzle]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Logic

By logical deduction I've got as far as this:

> [image: almost completed grid]

(black squares are filled, grey are definitely not filled, white are still unknown)

I think that's as much as we can do with pure logic, so here must be where the three possible solutions appear.

### Number 1

There's an L-shaped hole in the middle. If we assume the middle cell of the L is filled, we get the following solution:

> [image: first solution]

### Numbers 2 and 3

Now we assume the middle cell of that L is *not* filled. The two solutions arising here are almost identical, so I'm showing them in one image:

> [image: other solutions]

The empty $2\times2$ square near the top must have two diagonally opposite squares filled and the other two empty, but it could be either way round.

Comment: Wow. Wow. How did you do it so fast?

Comment: @Alto There's only a limited number of types of logical step necessary to solve these puzzles. I got a lot of practice with [these](http://www.kaser.com/dr.html) around 15 years ago. There were a few (2 or 3?) points in the solving process when I had to pause for a while and hunt for the next step, but once you get an "in", there's usually a small avalanche of deductions following it. (Hmm ... maybe I should write a tutorial for solving this type of puzzle, [like I did before](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/48017/5373) ...)

Comment: @Alto - it sounds like you are not familiar with nonograms. There are several free nonogram apps with puzzles like these. The puzzles can yield a random pattern, but most of the apps result in a picture when you are finished - sometimes a very detailed one. I thought you might enjoy this type of puzzle - I do