# Pensive Nonogram - Two-Colour Puzzle

Tags: logical-deduction, no-computers, grid-deduction, nonogram

Fourth two-colour puzzle in the 32nd issue of Mega Pixel Puzzles by Puzzler.. I’ve made some progress, but I am stuck. Can you help me find my next move in it? (The puzzle is below)

[image]

Comment: Not enough for a full answer, but the 14 in row 8 is bounded by the left edge *and* the blue square on col 21, so your observation that cols 11-14 are black can be extended the other way by another 4, covering cols 7-10. (Also, welcome to Puzzling!)

Comment: Are you sure row 22, column 17 is meant to be an X, I seem to be running into problems later in the puzzle if that is an X

Answer (score 1):

The 7 on top is even further restricted. Every pattern 1-2-1 downwards helps you to exclude. For example it can not be to the left because of 1-2-1 starting in 4th column. Meaning the three in third row must be left.
Also the 8 in fifth row has at least one field safe. A lot more if the signs to the right are right.

Comment: Why does 1-2-1 exclude an option for the 7 on top?

Comment: It feels like we should have a nonogram glossar. The 2 leeds to a "hit" on the second row. Because of the 1 right and left of it, it will become a single, but you do not have a 1 in the second row. So you can not have that.

Comment: Aha, nice deduction! And yeah, making a nonogram guide with all the possible types of deductive steps needed (kind of like [this one I made](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/48017/5373) for another type of grid-deduction puzzle) is on my to-do list.

Answer (score 1):

Some more values can be found in the 23rd row from what you have currently, and can lead to the finishing of column 17.

> Start by counting the possible placements for each grey square after the blue ones in row 23 [image: Possibility 1] [image: Possibility 2]

Then look for overlap:

> the overlapping values can lead to these fill ins [image]

---

Intial post:
Another way you can fill in some more of the puzzle is with some of the blue in the upper right hand corner.

> If you count through the closest to the top possibilities for grey squares before blue is possible in the first couple of rows, you can prove that the blue squares in the first rows must be over on the right side of the image. [image: Grey Count]

From there you can find these squares in particular:

> [image: New values]

Note these are not the only ones you can find from this but just the first few I found.

---

In case anyone else would like a blank of this puzzle of included it below. If I have misread any parts of the puzzle please let me know. Thanks Kruga for pointing out the mistake earlier.

> [image: Blank Puzzle]

Comment: Your blank puzzle is missing a black 1 in column 20